# How to add foreign key value in insert query - mysql - CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, foreign-keys

I have the following insert query:

```
$salarystuff = array('salary' => $salary, 'from_date' => $salary_from_date, 'to_date' => $salary_to_date);

        $this->db->insert('salaries', $salarystuff);
```

The salary table has columns: emp_no| salary| from_date| to_date  (I'm using the database available from dev.mysql.com.

But it gives me an error 1452 saying foreign key constraint. How do I reference to the key value in the other table to be able to insert into this table?

This is the error message:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`employees`.`salaries`, CONSTRAINT `salaries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>
> INSERT INTO `salaries` (`salary`, `from_date`, `to_date`) VALUES
>   ('1000000', '2012-12-27', '2013-01-16')

Thank you

edit: I'm trying the following

First I create the record in the employees table using this function:

```
function add_emp($firstname,$lastname,$gender,$date_of_birth,$jobtitle,$dept,$hiredate)
    {

        $data = array(  'first_name' => $firstname, 
                        'last_name' => $lastname,
                        'gender' => $gender,
                        'birth_date' => $date_of_birth,
                        'hire_date' => $hiredate);

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->insert('employees', $data);
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        {
            $msg = "Adding the new employee failed.";
            return $msg;
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "Successfully Added Employee.";
            return $msg;
        }
    }
```

and then in another function I add the salary:

```
function add_salary($firstname,$lastname,$gender,$date_of_birth,$jobtitle,$dept,$hiredate,$salary, $salary_from_date,$salary_to_date)
    {
        $this->db->select('emp_no');
        $this->db->from('employees');
        $this->db->where('first_name', $firstname);
        $this->db->where('last_name', $lastname);
        $this->db->where('gender', $gender);
        $this->db->where('hire_date', $hiredate);
        $this->db->where('birth_date', $date_of_birth);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $selected_employee = $this->db->get();

        $salarystuff = array('emp_no' => $selected_employee, 'salary' => $salary, 'from_date' => $salary_from_date, 'to_date' => $salary_to_date);
        $this->db->insert('salaries', $salarystuff);
    }
```

both of which are in the model. Then in the controller I call both functions:

$employee_insert = $this->user->add_emp($firstname,$lastname,$gender,$date_of_birth,

```
$jobtitle,$dept, $hiredate);

        $salarythings = $this->user->add_salary($firstname,$lastname,$gender,$date_of_birth,$jobtitle,$dept,$hiredate,$salary, $salary_from_date,$salary_to_date);
```

But I get an error because there is no value in the emp_no field...I think it might be the line:

```
$selected_employee = $this->db->get();

            $salarystuff = array('emp_no' => $selected_employee,
```

My error message is:

> Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to insert into the salaries table, but you aren't specifying what employee the salary record is for.  You would need to provide a value for the `emp_no` column that is in the `employees` table.

ETA:

Glad you posted more code - what you should do is modify your `add_emp` function so that it returns the id of the employee that was created (I'm assuming here that `emp_no` is and auto-increment column in your database).  Like so:

```
function add_emp($firstname,$lastname,$gender,$date_of_birth,$jobtitle,$dept,$hiredate)
{

    $data = array(  'first_name' => $firstname, 
                    'last_name' => $lastname,
                    'gender' => $gender,
                    'birth_date' => $date_of_birth,
                    'hire_date' => $hiredate);

    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('employees', $data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        //$msg = "Adding the new employee failed.";
        //return $msg;
        return -1; // indicates failure
    }
    else
    {
        //$msg = "Successfully Added Employee.";
        //return $msg;
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

Note that the code that calls `add_emp` will need to change a bit to look at the return value as an integer instead of a message now, but now you have the id of the employee and you can use that in your add_salary function instead of having to pass in all that other data, like so:

```
function add_salary($emp_no,$salary, $salary_from_date,$salary_to_date)
{
    $salarystuff = array('emp_no' => $emp_no, 'salary' => $salary, 'from_date' => $salary_from_date, 'to_date' => $salary_to_date);
    $this->db->insert('salaries', $salarystuff);
}
```

So the code to add an employee and their salary would be something like this:

```
$emp_no = add_emp([Your parameters]);
if ( $emp_no > 0 ) {
   add_salary($emp_no, [other parameters]);
} else {
   // Show some error message that the employee creation failed.
}
```

EDIT AGAIN:

If you ignore my advice above, the simple answer to why you are getting an error is because `$selected_employee` is a result set and not an actual employee number.  You would need to change that code like so:

```
$selected_employee = $this->db->get();
$result = $selected_employee->result();
$emp_no = $result[0]->emp_no;

    $salarystuff = array('emp_no' => $emp_no, 'salary' => $salary, 'from_date' => $salary_from_date, 'to_date' => $salary_to_date);
    $this->db->insert('salaries', $salarystuff);
```

Comment: yes that's what i'm trying to do, but how? can i use active records to retrieve that?

Comment: Active Record is just a pattern, nothing less nothing more. You should have a reference to which customer you would like to insert data for, and you should use that reference to do the insert. (the reference i was talking about is the customer id most likely)

Comment: I think I've gotten that if you would kindly look at my edit, but its not getting it. I think the problem is the $selected_employee. The error I'm getting is: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string

Comment: @Xnoise - looks like he's talking about active record in the context of the codeigniter framework

Comment: @AZ1 - ok, added another edit to solve that specific problem :)

Comment: @Eric Petroelje thanks for helping, I'm trying your solution but am back to the error message of the foreign key (1452)

Comment: @EricPetroelje Sorry it took me so long to reply, was bursting with joy! the last edit you made was perfect. I hope I didn't come off as ignoring your advice, was following it like a sheep actually! Thank you :)